# Proving a function is bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Suppose set $A =\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and set $B = \{w, x, y, z\}$. Prove that the function, $f: A \to B$ is both injective and surjective (bijective). Use any function.

Comment: How can I if you don't tell me what the function is? There are functions $f:A\to B$ which are bijective and others which are not.

Comment: You want to prove that THERE IS some function $f: A \rightarrow B$ such that $f$ is bijective or you forgot to mention the function you want to prove that is bijective?

Comment: It would make more sense to have to prove that if $f$ is injective, then it's bijective

Comment: Or perhaps you want to prove that *in this particular case* a function $\;f:A\to B\;$ is injective if and only if it is surjective...?

Comment: I guess you just need a function

Comment: It's very likely that the OP just needs to show that the two sets have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much sense in this question. 
You can construct a function that is bijective and a function that isn't.

For example:

f(t) = 
$$\begin{cases} w, t = 1\\
x, t = 2\\
y,  t = 3\\
z,  t = 4\\
\end{cases}$$

This $f$ is bijective.

And take $f(t) = w$, for all $ t \in A$. Then $f$ is not bijective!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you just need to show that $|A|=|B|$. In this case, a constructive proof will suffice, so we need to show that there exists a bijective function $f:A \to B$. I'll do it for two "different" sets, but the proof will go exactly the same way.

$A =\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ and set $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\}$

Define $f(a_i)=b_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Proving that this function is bijective is a little strange, since there really is no "proof," you just need to check all cases (which are finite, and in fact, there are only four.)

*Surjective:* Notice that $B=\bigcup_{i \in \{1,2,3,4\}}b_i$. Then, let $b_i \in B$. Then, since $f(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, we are done.

*Injective:* Suppose that $f(a_i)=f(a_j)$. Then $b_i=b_j$. But then $i=j$, implying that $a_i=a_j$.